# Javascript to trigger an alert message on a form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, sweetalert

I have a PHP page with a form:

```
<form method="POST" action="multimod.php" id="multiple">
  <!-- some checkboxes here -->
  <input type="image" name="submit" src="img/upd.png" alt="modify" class="multi" />
</form>
```

Then I want to trigger an alert on submit. When the image is clicked on, a sweetAlert message is triggered:

```
<script>
$('input.multi').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
swal({
        title: "a title",
        text: "some text",
        type: "warning",
        confirmButtonText: 'yes',
        cancelButtonText: 'no',
        showCancelButton: true,
},
function(){
  document.forms["multiple"].submit();
});
});
</script>
```

As you can see the `id` of the form ("multiple") is used to reference it in the Javascript function.

It works for me, but I wonder if the syntax of the script is actually correct. I found this workaround online, and maybe there are better ways of doing it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [improving working code in a non-specific way](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Well, I am trying to find a specific way to improve it.

Comment: SO is for programming issues/problems. You should post this on the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site instead, since it's about reviewing and improving already working code.

Comment: I didn't know about the "Code Review" section. Thanks, and sorry for bothering.

Comment: Don't really get the urge to downvote it, though. Somebody might have found the piece of code useful..

Comment: @Alex SO is for specific and targeted questions. This is not quite one of them, because you don't know what you're looking for. That strikes some people as "unclear", which is one of the reasons for downvoting. Don't think too much of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to trigger it on submit, there is no reason to add a listener on the button.

```
<script>
function onFormSubmit() {
  alert("Before submitting to server!");
  return true; // allow the submission!
}
</script>
<form onsubmit="return onFormSubmit();" method="POST" action="multimod.php" id="multiple">
  <!-- some checkboxes here -->
  <input type="image" name="submit" src="img/upd.png" alt="modify" class="multi" />
</form>
```